# At what point are the gods pleased?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

I have the priory unlocked, but every offer I make angers the gods, and gives me a negative effect, like vulnerability or more traps. How much do I have to offer to satisfy the gods and get a good run? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 3):

### It is random, and you can only *influence* the Gods.

[According to gamezebo.com:](http://www.gamezebo.com/2015/06/05/must-build-boat-tips-cheats-strategies/)

> The Priory’s modifiers / blessings are unpredictable, and the result seems only influenced by what you give, not determined by it. For instance, we gave 300 of each currency and received a neutral modifier (Wanderers). On our next run, we offered 400 of each currency and received a negative modifier (Power Monsters). There is no magic number that will guarantee a good blessing from the Priory; it’s a gamble.

Answer (score 1):

The information in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/227510/) is not true. I have 100% consistency with either rich or easy chests if I donate 2000 gold and over 300 of each brain and brawn. These seems like a lot but you keep the blessing as long as you continue the same run.